# 2-body problem with Fortran 95

Tags: fortran, newton-method

I am trying to implement the N-body problem using Fortran 95. Before generalizing it to N bodies, I am first trying to calculate the motion of a single orbiting body (body 2 in my code below) around a fixed one (body 1 in the code below). The problem is the output is not correct, but I can't find the error with my equations! This is what I am trying to implement:

$V_{2,x} \leftarrow V_{2,x} - \frac{ G \times M_1 \times (x_2-x_1)}{r^3} \times dt$

$V_{2,y} \leftarrow V_{2,y} - \frac{ G \times M_1 \times (y_2-y_1)}{r^3} \times dt$

$x_2 \leftarrow x_2 + V_{2,x} \times dt$

$y_2 \leftarrow y_2 + V_{2,y} \times dt$

This is my code:

```
program gravitation
implicit none

integer :: k, total
real, dimension(2) :: M, x, y, Vx, Vy
real, parameter :: G = 6.6738E-11, pi = 3.1415926
real :: time, dt, r

dt = 1000. ! dt = 1000 seconds
total = 5000 ! total number of points to be output 

M(1)=1.9891E+09 ! Sun's mass
x(1)=0.
y(1)=0.
Vx(1)=0.
Vy(1)=0.

M(2)=5.9736E+03 ! Earth's mass
x(2)=1.4960E+11 ! Earth's average orbit as initial point
y(2)=0.
Vx(2)=0.
Vy(2)=2.9786E+04 ! Earth's average orbital speed

open(unit=101,file="a.txt")
write(101,*) "time, x, y"
write(101,"(E10.4,2(A1,1x,E10.4))") 0., ",", x(2), ",", y(2)

do k=1,total
  r = sqrt( (x(2)-x(1))**2 + (y(2)-y(1))**2 )
  Vx(2) = Vx(2) - G * M(1) * dt * (x(2)-x(1)) / r**3 ! i.e., Vx2 = Vx2 - G.M.dt.(x2-x1)/r^3
  Vy(2) = Vy(2) - G * M(1) * dt * (y(2)-y(1)) / r**3
    x(2) = x(2) + Vx(2) * dt
    y(2) = y(2) + Vy(2) * dt
  write(101,"(E10.4,2(A1,1x,E10.4))") k*dt, ",", x(2), ",", y(2)
enddo

end program gravitation
```

The output file shows that the x position of the second body does not change at all (it is stuck at the initial value of 0.1496E+12), while the y position changes.

Does anyone see what is the problem here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: My suspicion is that your units need work. I haven't checked closely, but I have coded these problems and getting those correct is the first issue to deal with. Try printing your computed acceleration to make sure it is reasonable.

Comment: The usual question applies: What have you done to debug your problem? Which line do you suspect is wrong? Have you run your program in a debugger to inspect why a variable does not change when you expect it to change? Etc.

Comment: @TomDickens I don't think the problem is with my units. I double checked them, and they seem to be all correct (standard SI units). A dt of 1000s seem to be fair as well, and I actually played around with this value but nothing really helps the output...

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I don't think this problem is about debugging, but rather about the implementation itself. I think there is something wrong with my equations, but I can't seem to spot the mistake. I tried several initial positions and initial velocities for body 2, plotted all of them and nothing seems to come even close to be an orbit. I was that someone here who would already have implemented this sort of algorithm could point me in the right direction concerning the computation itself.

Comment: @TomDickens Tom, you actually were right. I went to triple check my units, and it turned out that I read wrongly the table of masses of the planets in the solar system... the numbers in the table were not Kg, but actually in Yg (10^21 kg)... now everything is running smooth. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: I have written working codes like this, and it is standard to use units such that $GM_{sun} = 1$, then the unit of time is the year and the unit of distance is the AU (astronomical unit = mean distance from Earth to Sun). Then you get numbers that are of a reasonable size to work with - for example, JPL specifies state vectors for solar system objects in terms of AU and AU/year. These numbers are of order 1-10 or so...

Comment: @TomDickens That sounds clever, I will consider changing all my units to more "astronomical-friendly" ones. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f: you should write up the fix as an answer and accept it, it'll be easier for users in posterity to see it and learn from the example.

Comment: @DanielShapero Thanks for reminding me of that, below you will find the corrected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with the code above was with the values of the masses. By simply correcting the masses of both astronomical bodies to their proper value, the simulation runs pretty well. Below, I added the corrected code (still using all units in SI, i.e., kg, m, seconds); but as one of the users previously commented (TomDickens), probably the best approach for this kind of program would be to use astronomical units, such as AU for distance, year for time and $G \times M_{sun}=1$ concerning masses.

```
program gravitation
implicit none

integer :: k, total
real(8), dimension(2) :: M, x, y, Vx, Vy
real(8), parameter :: G = 6.6738D-11
real(8) :: time, dt, r

dt = 3600. ! dt = 3600 = 1h
total = 10000 ! total number of points to be output 

M(1)=1.9891D+30 ! Sun's mass
x(1)=0.
y(1)=0.
Vx(1)=0.
Vy(1)=0.

M(2)=5.9736D+24 ! Earth's mass
x(2)=1.4960D+11 ! Earth's average orbit as initial point
y(2)=0.
Vx(2)=0.
Vy(2)=2.9786D+04 ! Earth's average orbital speed

open(unit=101,file="2-body_output.txt")
write(101,*) "time, x, y" ! CSV file header
write(101,*) 0., ",", x(2), ",", y(2) ! initial position

do k=1,total
  r = sqrt( ( x(2) - x(1) )**2 + ( y(2) - y(1) )**2 ) ! distance between object 1 and 2
  Vx(2) = Vx(2) - G * M(1) * dt * ( x(2) - x(1) ) / r**3 ! i.e., Vx2 = Vx2 - G.M.dt.(x2-x1)/r^3
  Vy(2) = Vy(2) - G * M(1) * dt * ( y(2) - y(1) ) / r**3
  x(2) = x(2) + Vx(2) * dt ! calculating new x position
  y(2) = y(2) + Vy(2) * dt
  time = k * dt
  write(101,*) time, ",", x(2), ",", y(2)
enddo

end program gravitation
```